# How to extract text from between html tag using Regular Expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract text from between the **textarea** tag.

How can I do it using regular expressions?

```
<textarea rows="20" cols="70" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;"data-input-file="1">
 abc_text
 #include<abc>
 xyz
</textarea>
```

Comment: you can use xml parsing libraries to exact data from the xml. e.g. `lxml`, we can you from the regular expression but it is risky according to me.

Comment: I have tried using Beautifulsoup but textarea contains '<>' as well so it was giving undesired results.

Comment: `soup.find('textarea').text`

Comment: I also need to extract '#include<abc>' but beautifulsoup is extracting only '#include'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try,

```
>>> print [x.strip() for x in re.findall('<textarea.*?>(.*)</textarea>', content, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)]
['abc_text\n #include<abc>\n xyz']
```

Comment: Up-voted, if content in the `textarea` tag contains new line i.e. `\n` then above re will work?

Answer (score 1):

XML is not valid according to XML rules. Opening and ending tag mismatch.

```
#include<abc>
```

`<abc>` is opening tag, not content.

XML parsing libraries not going to parse invalid Input.

---

**Modification Input:**

If you change `#include<abc>` to `#include&lt;abc&gt;` then following will work:

```
>>> import lxml.html as PARSER
>>> root = PARSER.fromstring(data)
>>> root.xpath("//textarea/text()")
['\n abc_text\n #include<abc>\n xyz\n']
>>>
```

---

**By RE:**

```
>>> data
'<textarea rows="20" cols="70" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;"data-input-file="1">\n abc_text\n</textarea>'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('<textarea[^>]*>[^<]*</textarea>', data)
['<textarea rows="20" cols="70" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;"data-input-file="1">\n abc_text\n</textarea>']
>>>
```